# How to get Profile Info from the Google API in c#

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-dotnet-client

I am buiding a web application in vs2017 with c#. My requirement is allow user to do login through Google login. 
Please note I do not know MVC so I have to write the code in .cs page

I have read this article https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in and implemented it accordingly.

I have also created the oAuth client ID and client secret.

I have also installed - Install-Package Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2 -Version 1.38.0.1532

I am totally blank as how to proceed further. I have read so many article but I don't know how to implement it in c# code.

How do I send the access token to an API - there are so many API's - which will get me all these information viz First name, Last name, Date of birth or Age, Phone Number, Email, Address, City or town, Postal code?

I understand that People API will fetch me email and full name.

I would appreciate if someone could please help me going forward as what more nuget package should I install and how do I send token to the API through c# code

1. Created a button in Test.aspx page

   ```
   function onSignIn(googleUser) {
       var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
       console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:

       var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
       console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

       console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
       console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
       console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.


       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:53028/1.aspx');
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       xhr.onload = function () {
           console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
       };
       xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
   }
   ```

On 1.aspx.cs

```
string idToken = Request.Form["idtoken"].Trim();
```

I want First name, Last name, Date of birth or Age, Phone Number, Email, Address, City or town, Postal code.

Update: I have added these lines of code in my .cs file and it return the name.

```
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
           new ClientSecrets
           {
               ClientId = "1basa5.apps.googleusercontent.com",
               ClientSecret = "AG0LvAwZAD123"
           },
           new[] { "profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" },
           "me",
           CancellationToken.None).Result;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new PeopleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "M_Test",
        });

        PeopleResource.GetRequest peopleRequest = service.People.Get("people/me");
        peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField = "person.names";
        Person profile = peopleRequest.Execute();
```

Now what is the use of id_Token here then? Should I do not pass it xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token); from the client page?

Comment: Would you please open a new question with your update rather than adding to the original question this update is not related to the original question.  Its a completely new question.  Then i would be happy to answer that.

Comment: @Happy Singh Please let me know, which approach you took finally to accomplish it!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call to the people api and request the information just set the authorization header and add the access token.

```
GET /v1/people/me HTTP/1.1
Host: people.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer [Access Token]
```

Your not actually using the .net client library.  You might want to try following [Web authorization](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

Note this information is only going to be available if the user filled it in. there are also a few other limitations.

- First name, Last name  (only name is returned)
- Date of birth or Age (only returned if set public)
- Phone Number (only returned if set public)
- Email (only returned with email scope)

Comment: Thanks DaImTo, my question is I am getting the idtoken in .cs file, now how should I call I people api and pass this token and get the required info?

Comment: You cant id tokens are not used for calling the API access tokens are.   You need to use the access token.    You could decrypt the id token its a  jwt id token there are some user claims in that but not everything you are looking for.

Comment: So what would be the best solution to get the required information in .cs file?

Comment: Follow the tutorial i linked rather then coding it yourself would be the best solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

i'am use this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#protectauthcode)
1. In first you need get code. You must generate url for user like this:

```
                    var serv = app.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
                    var str = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth" +
                        "?scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email") +
                        "&response_type=" + "code" + 
                        "&access_type=offline" + 
                        "&client_id=" + clien_id +
                        "&state=" + "test" +
                        "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(serv + "/index.html?action=google");

                    app.Response.Redirect(str);
```

2. in action=google you can use this function to exchange code on token.

   ```
   static bool GetAccessToken(string access_code, string redirect_url, out string token)
   {
       try
       {
           var clien_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["google_app_id"];
           var clien_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["google_app_secret"];

           var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");

           webRequest.Method = "POST";

           string parameters = $"code={access_code}&client_id={clien_id}&client_secret={clien_secret}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&grant_type=authorization_code";

           var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);

           webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

           var postStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

           // Add the post data to the web request
           postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
           postStream.Close();

           var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
           postStream = response.GetResponseStream();

           var reader = new StreamReader(postStream);
           var tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();

           var pat = "\"access_token\"";
           var ind = tmp.IndexOf(pat); 

           if (ind != -1)
           {
               ind += pat.Length;

               ind = tmp.IndexOf("\"", ind);

               if (ind != -1)
               {
                   var end = tmp.IndexOf("\"", ind + 1);

                   if (end != -1)
                   {
                       token = tmp.Substring(ind + 1, end - ind - 1);

                       return true;
                   }
               }
           }

           token = tmp;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(e);

           token = e.Message;
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```
3. Get user profile

   ```
       var access_code = app.Request.QueryString["code"];

       if (access_code == null)
       {
           return;
       }

       var serv = app.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
       var access_token = "";

       if (!GetAccessToken(access_code, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(serv + "/index.html?action=google"), out access_token))
       {
           return;
       }

       var res = "";
       var web = new WebClient();

       web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

       try
       {
           res = web.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + access_token);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return;
       }
   ```